# When making labels is it possible to have the first word be to the left then the second word to the right?

Tags: microsoft-word, label

When making labels is it possible to have the first word be to the left then the second word to the right? For example on the first line I have a name and a State the second line I have a number and a code.  I want the name on the first line and the number on the second line on the left and I want the AR and the NCU to the far right of the labels.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgcXh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Select the whole label. Insert a right align tab where you want the words "on the right" to align using the ruler at the top. You can also insert tabs under format paragraph or format style.

Now you can just insert a tab space between the word on the left and the word on the right for each line.

BTW you will probably have to insert tab spaces using ctrl+tab, because Word treats labels like table cells, moving to the next label when you press tab instead of inserting a tab space

Comment: Tab settings are paragraph formatting and can be applied via styles. At least in the Windows version, the tab within a table is inserted using Ctrl+Tab.See my page on left-and-right alignment: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/justification.htm#Flush

Comment: @Charles Kenyon ooops. 48 hours without sleep - edited to change to ctrl+tab, thanks for catching that one.  As for style formatting, that was already stated in the opening paragraph, just not expanded on.